# How to pass this mysql addition to jpql?

Tags: mysql, jpql

Good afternoon, I have this query which I have in MYSQL and it gives me a data of a sum but I want to transfer that query to JPQL language.

```
 SELECT SUM(`TOTAL_HORA_HOMBRE`) FROM `tiempos` WHERE `ID_ORDENTRABAJO` = 4696;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JPQL syntax is very close to standard SQL.

But MySQL uses the back-ticks to delimit table names and other identifiers. This is nonstandard.

Take out the back-ticks and I believe this query will work fine.

```
SELECT SUM(TOTAL_HORA_HOMBRE) FROM tiempos WHERE ID_ORDENTRABAJO = 4696;
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-querylanguage.htm#BNBTG for full documentation on JPQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a native SQL query. To use JPQL you have to have a java class annotated with the @Entity annotation and @Table annotation and pointing to the tiempos table.

If your entity would look like:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "tiempos")
    public class Tiempos {

    @Column(name = "TOTAL_HORA_HOMBRE")
    Double totalHolaHombre;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ORDENTRABAJO")
    Ordentrabajo ordentrabajo;
    }
```

Then the JPQL query could look like:

```
SELECT SUM(t.totalHolaHombre) FROM Tiempos t WHERE t.ordentrabajo = :paramOrdentrabajo;
```